# Small server application

Tags: c#, android, server

I'm interested in programming a small server app that I can use to convert an old laptop into a home server. I don't think it needs to be too complex, I just want to be able to download my music and such onto other devices. My questions are:

- Could I do something like this in C#?
- Is it possible to set it up in a way that I can connect my mobile devices to transfer pictures and music?
- Are there any references that might help me with this? (Books, articles, etc.)?

I'm fresh out of school so my experience is minimal, so I'm sorry if these questions seem obvious. Also, my mobile devices are all Android, two of my PCs run Windows 10, and the one I want to act as the server runs Windows 7, but I can upgrade that if it will simplify things. Again, sorry if the questions are a little basic and thanks for taking the time to read.

Comment: The term you are searching for is **NAS server**

Comment: Yes you can do that with C# from XP to 10. Remove the Android tag as this has nothing to do with Android.